# xml feed parser from multiple sources, multiple url-source xml importers

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

[image]I can't seem to find a good module that does what my title says. Xpath XML Parser is limited to a single source isn't it?

I needed to be able to import xml feeds from different URLs towards the same target (e.g. mapped to a specific content type). Say, my website will publish contents from different client's websites using an xml specification defined by me. My website then will get all contents by importing all those xml sources towards the same content type so my site will list all contents from different 'sources' effectively. Say real estate listings coming from different real estate agencies/agents...

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

To me this seems like an exact use case for [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) plus [Feeds XPath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser).  It will be possible to map your custom XML spec to various fields and import content from as many sources as you want into nodes of the same content type.  I posted [an answer to another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/import-a-big-website-using-feeds-xpath-parser/7204#7204) which may give guidance on how to use it.

**Feeds:**

> - Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

**Feeds XPath Parser:**

> Feeds XPath Parser is a [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) plugin for parsing XML and HTML documents. It enables site builders to leverage the power of Feeds to easily import data from complex, external data sources. Each element you wish to extract is setup using configurable mapping queries, saving time for developers who would otherwise have to code complex, specific-use modules. It also enables end-users to build web scrapers and other useful tools within Drupal.

Comment: I have one question though.. Why is the url path to import located within the add new content as shown on the image I attached? Isn't this set up redundant? I mean the reason why I need the importer is to auto-import the content and map the xml fields to, say, 'commercial for rent' content-type as above.. Every submission of the content of this type would trigger importing, as opposed to setting up a cron to 'independently' import xml without having to manually add the new content of this type...

Comment: I see what you are saying.  An important concept of Feeds is that it will require two content types, one being the "feed", or the path to the data you are importing, and the other being the target, or the "Commercial for Rent" in your case.  There is a good tutorial at http://yadadrop.com/drupal-video/feeds-module-tutorial-aggregate-rss-atom.

Comment: sorry, but everything seems to be only using a single source. I have no clue as to how to make the xpath parser/feed to accept multiple url sources into one content type...

Comment: I think I found a way.. Thank you Chris! I will update this post once I found it to be a real solution to my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @jan this is precisely what I was looking for, was about to post a separate question. Can you perhaps explain conceptually what your solution was? Thanks

Comment: @Duncanmoo hope I'm not too late in explaining my solution. Apologize for the delay. I was able to pull this off using the above scenario, where I added an extra field to 'Identify' which source is this content coming from, ie. 'Client' field. Properties come from different 'vendors' or 'source' companies etc. Where, client 'A' will have 1 xml path. 'B' will have another different path. So with the above, If you 'add' a content from one client, you will have to specify a new content for the second client. Different sources, different content. Data was fetching properly in my case.